Android creating a socket and sending works in a subclass in an Activity as a thread, but doesn't work in a non-activity class or the main Activity
A socket connection and sending data from Android to PC. The process works fine as a thread in a subclass within a daughter activity, called QueryActivity extends AppCompat for testing, sending when a button is pressed like a chat app.
However I want to send data automatically: when capturing clipboard and for other "telemetries" in background threads/tasks.
If I create a thread of a copy of the same class in a separate file, a class library supposed to be for networking, or as an internal class in the main activity (ListActivity at the moment, if the "AppCompat"-ness plays a role), the socket connection can't be established, no route to host. The IP and ports are correct. One detail is that when the address is wrong, there is timeout, when the address is correct: no route to host, suggesting a firewall?
The Manifest permissions are set like this:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

I compile for Lollipop 5.0, SDK 21 (they say from 23 an interactive permission request is required).
The no-route happens either if the thread or an async task is created from a menu activation or in an event processing (capturing the clipboard) - in the second case the event is captured, there's a feedback for the content, but the socket can't connect.
D/client: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
W/System.err: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:132)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:391)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:231)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at twenkid.android.basic.recreatetwenkid_reader_1.MyListActivity$ClientThread.run(MyListActivity.java:1510)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)

Sample Socket thread:
    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        private final String message, ip, port;

        ClientThread(String ip, String port, String message) {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;
            this.message = message;
            Log.d("IP:", this.ip );
            Log.d("PORT:", this.port );
            Log.d("this.message ", this.message );
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // the IP and port should be correct to have a connection established
                // Creates a stream socket and connects it to the specified port number on the named host.
                Enumeration e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
                while(e.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
                    Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
                    while (ee.hasMoreElements())
                    {
                        InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
                        System.out.println(i.getHostAddress().toString());
                        Log.d("run net", i.getHostAddress());
                    }
                }

                Log.d("ADDRESS", ip); //message);
                Log.d("ADDRESS", port); //message);
                Log.d("MESSAGE", message);
                client = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));  
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(message);  // write the message to output stream
                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                // closing the connection
                client.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("client", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // updating the UI
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //text.setText(""); //add in history etc.
                    SwitchView("Main");
                }
            });
        }

    }

EDIT 15.5.2024: A new discovery from the debugger:
From the QueryActivity there is a valid local port (non-0)
Socket[addr=/192.168.100.6,port=8089,localport=35096]
While when host unreachable the port is 0.
I started to call with either:
Socket client = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port), null, 0);
//that should acquire local port automatically
or forcing to a known good one:
Socket client = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port), null, 35096);
The last one is called within a View that captures touch events, but overall it connects as it should only from a thread created in an OnClickListener in a QueryActivity extends AppCompat ... Otherwise the connection can't be established.
Socket[addr=/192.168.100.106,port=8089,localport=0]
Also I tried with running a Service to initiate the thread, but it ends up with the same result.
An explicit Inbound rule was set (Windows) for ports 8081-8090, but it worked without it for the QueryActivity. It didn't help either.
I added also an Outbound rule allowing the ports on Windows, if the high value ports are a problem, but it doesn't help.
The simple server side code is closing the connection after receiving (in order not to hold it).
Something is blocking the connection, but what...?
Edit #2 16.5.2024: I managed to make it work with a workaround: when wanting to send, programmatically pressing a button from the active view and calling the socket thread from the onClick event.
As of the possible blocks: there's a setting called "network_security_config.xml" that can be added for allowing non-encrypted open-text transmission, even in the LAN. However it still doesn't help for another device, facing: "permission denied" error with  yet unknown reason:
D/client: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.100.6 (port 8089) from /:: (port 0): connect failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.100.6 (port 8089) from /:: (port 0): connect failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:137)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:570)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:450)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at twenkid.android.basic.recreatetwenkid_reader_1.QueryActivity$ClientThread.run(QueryActivity.java:156)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:118)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:151)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
        ... 11 more


